# Don't load the same JQuery load file twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic container that updates when you click links by loading in the file name from the "data-target" attribute. I don't want the same link to be clicked twice however (effectively loading the same page twice).

Is there a way to prevent this?

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Set trigger and container variables
    var trigger = $('#nav ul li a'),
        container = $('#ajaxContainer');

    // Fire on click
    trigger.on('click', function(){
        // Set $this for re-use. Set target from data attribute
        var $this = $(this),
            target = $this.data('target');  

        // Load target page into container
        container.load(target);

        console.log(target);

        // Stop normal link behavior
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" data-target="/home.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-target="/modules/Movies/index.php">Movies</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="ajaxContainer">
    <img id="logo" src="/images/logo.png" />
    <?php include('home.php'); ?>
  </div>

  <script src="/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What kind of file are you loading? Is it a js that should be loaded to the page?

Comment: It's loading in PHP files using the "data-target" attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `data-target` and re-set it when the `load()` is completed (on callback parameter):

```
// Fire on click
trigger.on('click', function(){
    // Set $this for re-use. Set target from data attribute
    var $this = $(this),
        target = $this.data('target');  
    $this.removeAttr('data-target'); // delete de target

    // Load target page into container only if it's target set
    if(target) {
         container.load(target);
    }
    console.log(target);

    // Stop normal link behavior
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You can briefly see the attribute disappear and re-appear, but it doesn't actually stop the same file from loading multiple times

Comment: This code is prepared to load once and when it loads completely it allows to reload again

Comment: If you want to only execute once till the end of the page life, just remove the `load()` callback function (resetting the target)

Comment: Tried it. So the attribute removes fine but load() still manages to refresh itself.

Comment: Edited, now I write an `if()` that controls this behaviour. Test it and tell me :)

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thanks!